# loading same page in php on basis of query

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to do nothing if search field is left blank, and load another page if something entered. 
so, How to **load same php page** when input textbox value is **blank**, and a different php page when input text value is **not blank**...?

for e.g.

```
<input id="srch" type="text" name="query" >
```

if value of this textbox is "", then same php page should get loaded
else, other page....

is there any way in **php** or **javascript**..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple `onsubmit` function for your form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" onSubmit="return validate()" id="searchForm">
    <input id="srch" type="text" name="query" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    if(document.getElementById('srch').value != ''){
        document.getElementById('searchForm').action = 'YOUR_OTHER_PAGE';
    }
}
</script>
```

In the above example, then the form is submitted, it goes to a `validate()` function in javascript. This function quickly checks to see if the `#srch` is empty. If it's not then it changes the `action` of the form to the page that you designate. I set that value to `YOUR_OTHER_PAGE`, and you would have to change it to the appropriate page. If the value of `#srch` is empty then it keeps the action which I set as `PHP_SELF`.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, in the script that checks the contents of the query, you can do this:

```
if( isset($_GET['query']) && $_GET['query'] != '' ) {
    header('Location: someotherpage.php?query=' . urlencode($_GET['query']));
    exit();
}
```

This qill instruct the browser to go to someotherpage.php

Answer (score 0):

In PHP - after submiting the form - let's say to a script called `decide.php`

it's content:

```
if (!isset($_GET['query']) || $_GET['query']=='' )
    include "emptysearchlanding.php";
else
    include "somethingelse.php";
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code that I use you can decide what to do by using `inputString.length == 0` for blank input and just do if statement to execute your second function.
the code that I included in my answer is used to post the input automatically to the php file.

**javascript** :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lookup(inputString) {
if(inputString.length == 0) 
{
$('#suggestions').hide();
}
else
{
$.post("http://www.example.com/suggest.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
if(data.length > 0) {
$('#suggestions').show();
$('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
}
});
}
} 
function fill(thisValue) {
$('#inputString').val(thisValue);
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
function outoffocus() {
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
</script>
```

**HTML** :

```
<form id="search" action="/search.php" method="get"> 
<input type="text" name="search" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="outoffocus()" onfocus="lookup(this.value);"/>
<input type="submit" value="&nbsp;" />
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" >
 <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: @manoj you are welcome. please consider picking on of the answers as the right answer.